# Icinga-Web + Nginx - Unregistered handler

Tags: postgresql, nginx, ubuntu-16.04, icinga2, icingaweb

I installed **Icinga2** (*2.6.3-1*), **Postgres** (*9.5.6*), **nginx** (with PHP and Postgres dependencies) and **Icinga**-**web** (*1.13.1*) following [this tutorial](https://github.com/jpfluger/examples/blob/master/ubuntu-14.04/icinga2-server.md#install-icinga2) which are working perfectly. But now I am trying to run Icinga-web using nginx and I get this error:

```
-> 500 internal server error!

=== Error ===

Uncaught exception AgaviConfigurationException thrown !

=== Message ===

Configuration file "/home/alfred/icinga-web-1.13.1/lib/agavi/src/translation/data/
supplementalData.xml" does not have a registered handler
```

[image of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0X1MR.png)

I'm working on a Ubuntu 16.04 LTS VM with oracle VM VirtualBox.